# Powershell - cheking var is giving me the right results but Export-CSV gives numbers

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

what I want is that the `$report_groups` val gives me in Export-CSV the output that i get in Terminal. But i cant figure it why does he gives me Numbers.

```
$get_AD_Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter '*' | Select-Object Name
$report_groups = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach ($item in $get_AD_Groups) {
    $get_users =  $item.Name | Get-ADGroupMember | Select-Object Name
    $disabled_user = 0

foreach ($user in $get_users) {
    $status = $user.Name | Get-ADUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
    
    if(($status.ObjectClass -eq 'user') -and ($status.Enabled -ne 'True')) {
         $disabled_user++   
    }
}

if ($get_users.Count -eq $disabled_user) {
   $report_groups.Add($item.Name)
}
}

$report_groups | Export-Csv -Path "..\report.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force -Delimiter ";"
```

Now when i run `$report_groups` in Terminal i get the list of the AD Group BUT as soon i do the `Export-CSV` this is what i get:

[image: Should be AD Groups]

Comment: that means you are sending STRINGS to the export cmdlet. you need to send more complex, structured objects - PSCustomObject items for instance. take a look at >>> `'' | select *` <<< and you will see that it only has ONE property - named `Length`. [*grin*]

Comment: Omg, that helped me further. I'll go now and cry somewhere x).

Comment: glad to have "helped" a little ... [*grin*]

Comment: You're looking to find all AD Groups where all members (AD Users) are Disabled right?

Answer (score 0):

So thanks again to [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) for helping me on this.
Changes done.

```
$report_groups = @()

if ($get_users.Count -eq $disabled_user) {
        $fill = [PSCustomObject]@{
            AD_GROUP = $item.Name
        }
        $report_groups += $fill
    }
```